# Existence of a non-compact Cantor set.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Does there exist a metric space that is totally disconected and perfect but not compact?

Comment: ${\mathbb Q}$, ${\mathbb Q}_p$, etc.

Comment: Alternatively, if you want closed but not compact, consider $K + n$, the Cantor set shifted by $n \in \Bbb{Z}$, and then union the results as $n$ ranges over $\Bbb{Z}$.

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}$ is not perfect...

Comment: @user759562 I think that works, is every non-compact example homeomorphic to that set you proposed?

Comment: The Cantor set minus a point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - take [Baire Space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_space_(set_theory)). It is perfect, completely metrizable, and totally disconnected. It is not even locally compact.

Two common ways of writing baire space are:

- $\omega^\omega$, the space of all infinite strings of natural numbers (endowed with the product topology)
- $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$, the space of irrational numbers (endowed with the subspace topology)

It is not clear that these spaces should be homeomorphic, but in fact they are. This space is well studied in [Descriptive Set Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descriptive_set_theory) - see, for instance, Kechris "Classical Descriptive Set Theory" for more information.

**Edit:**

I just saw your question in the comments, and it is *not* the case that every noncompact, perfect, totally disconnected metric space is homeomorphic to the disjoint union of $\mathbb{Z}$ many copies of cantor space. Indeed, that space is locally compact, while baire space is not.

---

I hope this helps ^_^